# dynamically changing data model for JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a small GUI application, that processes mouse clicks, and stores them in a list:

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestGUI extends JFrame {

    private final List<String> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    private TestTree testTree;

    final JPanel canvas = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            for (final String object : objects) {
                final String[] parts = object.split("--");
                g.drawOval(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]), Integer.parseInt(parts[1]), 5, 5);
            }
        }
    };

    public TestGUI() {
        final Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        testTree = new TestTree(objects);
        cp.add(testTree, BorderLayout.EAST);
        setTitle("TestGUI");
        canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {}
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {}
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {}
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {}
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                objects.add(me.getX() + "--" + me.getY());
                testTree.update();
                canvas.repaint();
            }
        });
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I want to represent an overview of the list using a JTree at the side of the canvas. The class responsible for the JTree is as follows:

```
package test;

import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;

public class TestTree extends JPanel {

    final List<String> objects;

    private JTree tree;
    private final DefaultMutableTreeNode root;

    public TestTree(final List<String> theObjects) {
        objects = theObjects;

        root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root");
        tree = new JTree(root);

        add(new JScrollPane(tree));
    }

    private void updateTree(final List<String> objects) {
        root.removeAllChildren();
        final DefaultMutableTreeNode result = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(objects.size() + " objects");
        for (final String object : objects) {
            final DefaultMutableTreeNode objectNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(object);
            result.add(objectNode);
        }
        root.add(result);
        tree.updateUI();
    }

    public void update() {
        updateTree(objects);
        tree = new JTree(root);
        add(new JScrollPane(tree));
    }

}
```

So, which is the correct way of updating the JTree by submitting the list? Because after some clicks my application renders a seperate tree for each added element, instead of one tree that gets updated over time:
[image: screenshot]

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in method `update()` of class `TestTree`. You keep adding another `JScrollPane` to the `TestTree`. You only want one `JScrollPane`.

You correctly update the model of the `JTree` and that's all you need to do. The `JTree` will automatically update itself whenever its model changes.

Also, don't set the size of the `JFrame`. Set the size of its components and call method `pack()` which will make the `JFrame` big enough to contain all its components.

In the below code I have commented out the lines you need to remove from your code.

Class `TestTree`

```java
package test;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;

public class TestTree extends JPanel {
    final List<String> objects;

    private JTree tree;
    private final DefaultMutableTreeNode root;

    public TestTree(final List<String> theObjects) {
        objects = theObjects;
        root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root");
        tree = new JTree(root);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 490));
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    private void updateTree() {
        root.removeAllChildren();
        final DefaultMutableTreeNode result = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(objects.size() + " objects");
        for (String object : objects) {
            final DefaultMutableTreeNode objectNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(object);
            result.add(objectNode);
        }
        root.add(result);
        tree.updateUI();
    }

    public void update() {
        updateTree();
//        tree = new JTree(root);
//        add(new JScrollPane(tree));
    }
}
```

Class `TestGUI`

```java
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestGUI extends JFrame {

    private final List<String> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    private TestTree testTree;

    final JPanel canvas = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            for (final String object : objects) {
                final String[] parts = object.split("--");
                g.drawOval(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]), Integer.parseInt(parts[1]), 5, 5);
            }
        }
    };

    public TestGUI() {
        final Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        testTree = new TestTree(objects);
        cp.add(testTree, BorderLayout.EAST);
        setTitle("TestGUI");
        canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {}
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {}
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {}
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {}
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                objects.add(me.getX() + "--" + me.getY());
                testTree.update();
                TestGUI.this.pack();
                canvas.repaint();
            }
        });
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 490));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
//        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```